# Where and how to add StatusBar (not StatusStrip) in Visual Studio's toolbox?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, statusbar

How do I find the icon labelled `StatusBar` in Visual Studio's toolbox?

Comment: I am a little confused as to what you mean, do you mean a bar which shows the progress of a command? If so that is called a 'Progress bar'

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[StatusBar in Visual Studio 2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040578/statusbar-in-visual-studio-2010)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click the toolbox, Choose Items.  Locate StatusBar and tick it.  There might be more than one, use the one whose Directory column says "Global Assembly".