# StatusBar in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to find the System.Windows.Forms.StatusBar control in the ToolBox for a Visual Studio 2010 Windows Forms Project in Visual Basic.  I cannot seem to see it.  Is it somewhere in the "Common Controls" or "Containers" sections?  I cannot see it.  If someone can tell me what controls are to the top and bottom of it I would appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It's not there by default, because it's been replaced by the newer (and much nicer) `StatusStrip` control.

If you really need it, you can add it to any tab by right-clicking, then clicking *Choose Items*:

[image]